# How to find the most repeated line from a text and delete it from the whole text

Tags: python

I'm filtering tweets so I can do a sentiment analysis on them but there are repeating lines I want to avoid as they're just the name of the account, after the filtering the text is left like this:

[image: said text]

And as you can see, every other line is 'Ajuntament de Calvià  de Calvià', how could I delete the most repeated line and then delete that text from the whole file?

I tried this but all it does is find the longest repeating substring, which is not what I want:

```
def delete_lrns(string):  # delete longest repeating, non-overlapping substring
    x = open("FILTERED_" + string, encoding='utf-8')
    text = x.read()
    n = 10000
    lcs = [[0 for x in range(n + 1)]
           for y in range(n + 1)]

    res = ""  # To store result
    res_length = 0  # To store length of result

    # building table in bottom-up manner
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):

            # (j-i) > lcs[i-1][j-1] to remove
            # overlapping
            if (text[i - 1] == text[j - 1] and
                    lcs[i - 1][j - 1] < (j - i)):
                lcs[i][j] = lcs[i - 1][j - 1] + 1

                # updating maximum length of the
                # substring and updating the finishing
                # index of the suffix
                if lcs[i][j] > res_length:
                    res_length = lcs[i][j]
                    index = max(i, index)

            else:
                lcs[i][j] = 0

    # If we have non-empty result, then insert
    # all characters from first character to
    # last character of string
    if res_length > 0:
        for i in range(index - res_length + 1,
                       index + 1):
            res = res + text[i - 1]

    x.close()
    return res
```

Comment: I tried looking for the longest repeating substring but it doesn't work. Then I tried looking for the most repeated substring but doesn't work either. I wanted to make an algortihm that finds the most repeated substring of at least 'k' lenght but couldn't manage.

Comment: the "line" you mention also appears IN other lines

Comment: @azro done, yes that's why I also want to remove it from the whole file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
def remove_duplicate_lines(name):
    lines_seen = set()  # holds lines already seen
    outfile = open("NODUP_FILTERED_" + name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    for line in open("FILTERED_" + name, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
        if line not in lines_seen:  # not a duplicate
            outfile.write(line)
            lines_seen.add(line)
#         else:
#             outfile = str(outfile.replace(line, ''))
    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
# function to remove duplicate texts
def remove_duplicate():
    # opens texts.txt in r mode as one long string and assigns to var
    texts = open('filename', 'r').read()
    # .split() removes excess whitespaces from str, return str as list
    texts = texts.split()
    # empty list to store non-duplicate e-mails
    clean_list = []
    # for loop to append non-duplicate texts to clean list
    for text in texts:
        if text not in clean_list:
            clean_list.append(text)
    return clean_list
    # close texts.txt file
    texts.close()
# assigns no_duplicate_texts.txt to variable below
no_duplicate_texts = open('no_duplicate_texts.txt', 'w')

# function to convert clean_list 'list' elements in to strings
for text in remove_duplicate():
    # .strip() method to remove commas
    text = text.strip(',')
    no_duplicate_texts.write(f"{text}\n")
# close no_duplicate_texts.txt file
no_duplicate_texts.close()
```

But this will generate a new file without the duplicates.

Hope it helps

Comment: Gives me errors, texts.close() is unreachable

Comment: umm ok i will work on fixing that right away

Comment: check my other answer for some reason its not letting me edit my original one but sadly the downside is that it doesn't delete the first duplicate and the last duplicate in the file i can't figure out anything else at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
count_dict = {} #This is to keep track of count of each line

with open('yourfile.txt', "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() #Open file and read, write to a list simultenously
for line in lines:
    count_dict[line] = lines.count(line) #Fill the dict to keep track

line_with_max_occurance = max(count_dict, key= lambda x: count_dict[x])

modified_lines = [i for i in lines if i != line_with_max_occurance or line_with_max_occurance not in line]

with open('your_new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in modified_lines:
        f.write(f"{line}\n")
```

Please note that this is for writing the content to a new file, not the same file.

If you want to modify the same file without the most repeated line, please use below instead of the file writing part in the code above:

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != line_with_max_occurance:
            f.write(line)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```py
lines_seen = set()

with open(".txt", "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in d:
        if i not in lines_seen:
            f.write(i)
            lines_seen.add(i)
    f.truncate()
```

downside is that it doesn't delete the first duplicate and the last duplicate in the file
Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I think linux command can do the job:
On my mac, this will work

```
➜  cat 1.txt  # abbbbb is the most freq line, it appeared 3 times 
abb
abc
abb
abbbbb
ababab
abbbbb
abbbbb
➜  cat 1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I _ printf "sed /^%s$/d 1.txt" _ | sh -s
abb
abc
abb
ababab
```

and of course you can display the appear time of the lines by

```
➜  cat 1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
   3 abbbbb
   2 abb
   1 abc
   1 ababab
```

Comment: you can create a cronjob on the machine, you can put a file in one original folder, and when the cronjob is triggered, the machine will extract the file from this folder and delete the most freq lines and put the whole new file to another folder.

Comment: Nice solution, but the question was tagged "python" and this does not use Python.

Comment: Yeah I know, cuz the business you working on give me feeling that you need the command line solution.I was wrong, and I think you can work it out by yourself using python

Comment: It’s not that hard